# Angular Bootstrap (ngx) datepicker inline

Tags: css, angular, datepicker

I want to make the ngx bootstrap datepicker inline instead of it appearing only when you click an input.

[ngx datepicker link](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Can someone help me achieve this? I've tried to add it in but there is absolute positioning and if I override it with relative positioning it doesn't work properly.

I just want to see this on the page inline without the need of having it inside an input field box:

[image: image of inline datepicker]

Thanks

There is a container input in the documentation which says:

> container: A selector specifying the element the datepicker should be appended
>   to. Currently only supports "body".

Any way to get around this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem - also getting it.  Datepicker appends to Body for me always. My body is always static due to my layout and I have a "wrapper" for content that is scrollable and I need the picker to be appended within the wrapper instead of body

Answer (score 0):

try this, set the height to `0` with `overflow: hidden` an leaving it on the page. It'll be there so the picker with position itself correctly but with no height the input will be invisible and still have the picker show up where its supposed to.

And you can set the [`isOpen` property](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#is-open) to true so its opened by default

```
<input bsDatepicker [isOpen]="true" style="height: 0; overflow: hidden; border: none; padding: 0;" />
```

Comment: didn't work unfortunately. The main issue is that its container is the body. And apparently you cant change that value in the documentation so i need a workaround

Answer (score 0):

in you global css `style.css` file give

```
bs-datepicker-container {

  position: relative !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

`!important` is required to coz it is having element level style so you need to override it.

Obvious: make toggle disable and show permanently.